# router push is not working with Vuex and JS Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

This is the `store.js` which handle vuex store and login and logout functions,

```
actions:{

    login({ commit }, creds){
        commit(LOGIN);
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() =>{
                axios.post('/oauth/token', creds).then((response) =>{
                Vue.auth.setToken(response.data.access_token, response.data.expires_in + Date.now());
                commit(LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                });
                resolve();
            }, 3000);
        });
    },

    logout({commit}){
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() =>{
                Vue.auth.destroyToken();
                commit(LOGOUT);
                resolve();
            }, 3000);
        });
        console.log('Successfully logged out');

    }

}
```

and login component is this,

```
login(){
    try{
       this.$store.dispatch('login', {
       username: this.user.email,
       password: this.user.password,
       client_id: 2,
       client_secret: 'wcw9GkgKMHXUnyZavawJWXgE3GhSubOADO6tKw99',
       grant_type: 'password'
     })
    } catch(error) {
          console.log('error');
      }
      finally{
        alert('Router Push')
          this.$router.push('/dashboard');
          console.log('success')
      }
  }
```

the problem is no matter where i place `router.push` its not working, but `alert` and `console.log` is working fine but page is not pushing to a specified path, after page fresh it works. But not soon after the alert pops up. What's wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

here is navigation guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{
 if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitor)){
      if(Vue.auth.isAuthenticated())
      {
           next({
               path: '/dashboard'
           });
      } else {
           next();
      }
 } else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isauth)){
      if( !Vue.auth.isAuthenticated())
      {
           next({
               path: '/login'
           });
      } else {
           next();
      }
 } else {
      next()

 }
});
```

Comment: Nothing in this code waits for the dispatch promise to complete

Comment: Do you perhaps have a pending navigation guard that has not called `next()`, thus preventing the navigation?

Comment: What's with the timeouts? Also, your `login` action will _resolve_ **before** the HTTP request completes. Is that intentional?

Comment: So you're attempting to navigate to `/dashboard` **before** you call `Vue.auth.setToken()` so presumably you are not authenticated at that stage and your navigation guard redirects you back to `/login`. See the linked duplicate post. Also, it's just awesome when you fix up somebody's code formatting so it's readable and they go and overwrite it again /s

Comment: @Phil no i just followed a tutorial and test it out, So if i place HTTP request after `resolve` would it works.

Comment: @ESYMASESYMAS no, it won't, because you never wait for the requests to complete / promises to resolve

Comment: @phil Thank you, i figured it out,

Comment: @ESYMASESYMAS best news I've heard all day. Congrats!